# How can i update a current value in a XML file using powershell?

Tags: c#, xml, powershell, tfs, system.io.file

Hello everyone i dont know if this question is asked before but i need to update couple of values in a xml file using powershell i have the following code it works local but on tfs it doesn't work i get the following error `System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "ReadAllText" with "1" argument(s): "Value cannot be null.`

And i have the following code

```
$EmployeeData= "C:\files\Employees.xml"
$oldEmployeeID= "23"
$NewEmployeeID= "25"

$content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($EmployeeData).Replace($oldEmployeeID, $NewEmployeeID)
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText($EmployeeData, $content)
```

localy it works but on tfs its crashes does anybody know why 
with the following error code

```
System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "ReadAllText" with "1" argument(s): "Value cannot be null.
```

Comment: Could you elaborate "on tfs it doesn't work"? Did you include the script in TFS build? How's your build definition like? Which version of TFS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use this. You can directly parse XML in powershell by type casting:

```
$EmployeeData= "C:\files\Employees.xml"
$oldEmployeeID= "23"
$NewEmployeeID= "25"

[XML]$content = Get-Content $EmployeeData
```

Then you can access **$content.elementId** or **$content.nodename**.

Follow **[THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42851548/getting-the-element-name-of-an-attribute-in-xml-using-powershell)** for your reference.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update values/tokens in a XML file during TFS build, a simple way is to use [Replace Tokens task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) or [Tokenization Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TotalALM.totalalm-tokenization) in your build definition.